# Aligning multiline formula to the right of equal sign

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment, align, best-practices

I would like to align a multiline formula to the right of an equal sign, as suggested by the [AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) (see below screenshot from p. 118).

[image]

I am not able to reproduce the same behavior. Here is my attempt to typeset the same example (after incorporating daleif's suggestion in the comments):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
E D_{m}(D_{m}-1) = {} & \frac{\widetilde{W}(m)}{m}+O(1) + \frac{1}{h_{1}^{2}} \log^{2} m\\
&+ 2 \frac{1}{h_{1}}\left( \frac{h_{2} -h_{1}^{2}}{h_{1}^{2}} - \frac{1}{h_{1}} \widehat{\gamma}' (-1) + \frac{\gamma -1}{h_{1}} \right) \log m \\
&- 2 \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{\Gamma(s_{k}) \widehat{\gamma}(s_{k})}{h^{2}(s_{k})}m^{-1-s_{k}} \log m + O(1).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the horizontal distance between the equal sign and the plus sign on the next line is slightly larger in my case.

How can I reproduce the alignment shown in the first picture?

Comment: It does give the right alignment, but you should also use ` = {} &  ` not `=&` otherwise the spacing after the `=` is wrong.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the feedback! Your solution is a big improvement, but still does not exactly reproduce the example in the picture. Any idea why?

Comment: Please explain where you think it does not match the image? Because it does.

Comment: The thing left might be the left padding on say _addtion_ `+`, but I'm that looks better that the alignment being right on the line. Note that it is a lot easier to see if you use boxes instead of actual quations.

Comment: @daleif Please see my edit.

Comment: Again you're not using ` = {} &` and I would not even bother with the plus not being straight to the `=`. Remember that the origins of the style guide is from before the invention of TeX (the maker of TeX even refers to the AMS style guide as far as I remember).

Comment: BTW the code you show does not correspond to the image you show. The code produces an image with less space after the `=`

Comment: @daleif Sorry I had forgotten to edit the code, but the picture was obtained with `= {} &`, as you suggested. Anyway I get your point, thanks.

Comment: I use this construction a lot my self in the manuscripts that I've edited, and I've never had anyone insist that the `+` be aligned directly on the left edge of the right-hand-side of the first row. As long as what you do is consistent, most will not care, even publishers. Consistency is key.

Comment: @daleif -- The AMS Style Guide referred to here is not the "original".  (The "original" is Swanson's [*Mathematics into Type*](https://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf); the corresponding reference would be section 3.35b on page 46.)  The `amsmath` equivalent appears in Table 3.1 on page 5, the `split` example, which uses `\quad` following the `&`; `align` works in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possibilities: one with a phantom `=`, another with an `aligned` environment nested in a displayed equation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
E D_{m}(D_{m}-1) &=\, \frac{\widetilde{W}(m)}{m}+O(1) + \frac{1}{h_{1}^{2}} \log^{2} m\\
&\phantom{{} = {}}+ 2 \frac{1}{h_{1}}\left( \frac{h_{2} -h_{1}^{2}}{h_{1}^{2}} - \frac{1}{h_{1}} \widehat{\gamma}' (-1) + \frac{\gamma -1}{h_{1}} \right) \log m \\
&\phantom{{} ={} }- 2 \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{\Gamma(s_{k}) \widehat{\gamma}(s_{k})}{h^{2}(s_{k})}m^{-1-s_{k}} \log m + O(1).
\end{align*}

    \[ %
E D_{m}(D_{m}-1) =\begin{aligned}[t] &\mkern 3mu\frac{\widetilde{W}(m)}{m}+O(1) + \frac{1}{h_{1}^{2}} \log^{2} m\\
&+ 2 \frac{1}{h_{1}}\left( \frac{h_{2} -h_{1}^{2}}{h_{1}^{2}} - \frac{1}{h_{1}} \widehat{\gamma}' (-1) + \frac{\gamma -1}{h_{1}} \right) \log m \\
&- 2 \sum_{k \neq 0} \frac{\Gamma(s_{k}) \widehat{\gamma}(s_{k})}{h^{2}(s_{k})}m^{-1-s_{k}} \log m + O(1).
\end{aligned} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]